# Touchable Opacity Requires Two Taps to Submit When Keyboard Open - Passing keyboardShouldPersistTaps to ScrollView Does Not Work - Fresh Out Of Ideas

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Sorry in advance if this seems like a repeat question.

The issue is well-documented: I have a View component.  Within that View I have a TouchableOpacity that functions as a submit button.  Within the ScrollView I have a TextInput.  When the user focuses the TextInput, the keyboard opens.  For UX purposes, I believe the user should be able to press the TouchableOpacity and the TouchableOpacity should register the press on the first attempt.  This is not the behavior.  The first press closes the keyboard, and then the user must press the TouchableOpacity again in order to submit the TextInput:

```js
    <View>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ messageBody: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmitting(values)}>
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values }) => (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.appButtonContainer}
              onPress={handleSubmit}>
              <CustomIcon name="send" size={15} 
              style={styles.icon} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Reply to post"
                style={styles.newMessageBox}
                value={values.messageBody}
                onChangeText={handleChange('messageBody')}
              />
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
```

I have tried the solution presented in this article: https://medium.com/react-native-training/todays-react-native-tip-keyboard-issues-in-scrollview-8cfbeb92995b

This same solution has been posted a dozen times between github and stack overflow: pass the keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' prop to ScrollView.  But it doesn't work.  I've tried passing the prop to every element.  I've tried changing the prop from 'always', to 'handled', to true.  I've tried wrapping the TouchableOpacity and the TextInput in ScrollView.  I've tried wrapping everything in ScrollView.  I've tried taking out Formik.  I've tried taking the styling to bare-bones.  I've tried swapping the positions of TextInput and TouchableOpacity.  Nothing works.

Any help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE 06/11/2021

I'd been poking at this issue here and there for the better part of a month before I finally figured it out.  Most of what I read implied that the keyboardShouldPersistTaps prop should go on the component that's the next level up from the TextInput - in my case, the ScrollView component.  In my case, this was not true.

In my case, the keyboardShouldPersistTaps prop had to go not on the next higher level component, but rather the highest level component that the user interacts with.  For me, this was a SectionList, within each TextInput was rendered.

I just about had a heart attack when it worked.

Comment: Hi Collin, please improve the description of the post to make it more readable to others. Now answering your question please move the touchableOpacity inside the scrollview to make the property keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' work.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you very much for your input.  As I mentioned in the body of my question, I previously tried wrapping both the Touchable Opacity and the TextInput in the ScrollView component.  It did not solve the problem.  I tried again today to confirm, and it still doesn't work.  Also, I edited the title of the question to make it more pertinent to the question; thank you for the tip.

Comment: I solved the problem and the solution is posted in an update in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the above edit, I'd been poking at this issue here and there for the better part of a month before I finally figured it out. Most of what I read implied that the keyboardShouldPersistTaps prop should go on the component that's the next level up from the TextInput - in my case, the ScrollView component. In my case, this was not true.

In my case, the keyboardShouldPersistTaps prop had to go not on the next higher level component, but rather the highest level component that the user interacts with. For me, this was a SectionList, within each TextInput was rendered.